# Can you use words like "free" and "brave" as nouns?

Tags: nouns

The phrase "Land of the Free / Home of the Brave" seems to use the word "free" as a noun, short for "the free **ones**" (free being an adjective). Does it count to say that free as used here is a noun, or is it just an adjective with a hidden noun? If the latter, are there any cases where free can be considered a noun? I keep thinking "the free", which makes sense as "the free (ones)", so it seems okay to call it a noun, even though the dictionary does not say it's a noun looking at Google.

Comment: These are [collective adjectives](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Collective-Adjectives.htm). There are many more examples; cf "Lifestyles of the rich and famous."

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/305305/is-there-a-term-for-the-use-of-adjectives-as-nouns

Comment: Yes that answers it, so then are collective adjectives "nouns", or no? They "act as nouns", so are they nouns?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brave definition 3 = noun.

Comment: What TaliesinMerlin's link should show is that the notion that a word "is" a given part of speech is a problematic way of thinking. Words *serve the purpose of* given parts of speech in a sentence. The link calls the phenomenon "nominalization," that is "making something a noun." It doesn't mean that "free is a noun," any more than I can claim to be a doctor just because I render first aid when there is no doctor. You can say I *fill the role of* a doctor in that moment, but it doesn't define me.

Comment: @AndyBonner Yes, and that's why I included the last line of my answer below. (On which I'd certainly appreciate any comments!)

Comment: "Give me your tired, your poor..."

Comment: The current answers haven't mentioned the issue of register or style: use of terms like "the free" is commoner in an elevated style such as a national anthem or other poetry or fine writing, while "free people" would be more common in day-to-day speech. So a question like *Can you use words like "free" and "brave" as nouns?* is more nuanced than yes or no, there is also the question of what is common or usual in different situations. (I'm not going to add this as a comment to an answer where the debate is so long some mod is probably going to come along and delete everything.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example, "free" and "brave" are often called "[collective adjectives](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Collective-Adjectives.htm)" or "[adnouns](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/adnoun)". The part of speech ascribed to these words is usually "adjective", and they are used in sentences as "nominals". Being nominals, they may function as subjects, objects, complements, etc.

Sometimes people call these words nouns, but in my experience, those people are usually using the word "noun" somewhat loosely, as a shorthand for "nominal". (Some people call gerunds "nouns", too, but I won't go off on that tangent . . .)

However, some adnouns can become "nominalized", i.e., become actual nouns. That appears to be the case in the example that k1eran cited in a comment (from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brave)):

> brave noun
> Definition of *brave* (Entry 3 of 3)
> 1 [in part borrowed from French, noun derivative of *brave* brave entry 1] : one with mental or moral strength to face danger, fear, or difficulty : one who is brave (see brave entry 1)
> // … none but the *brave* deserves the fair.
> — John Dryden

Of course, different dictionaries might have different opinions on this.

Comment: I've been dancing around the fact that "brave" is a quite different case from "free." Aside from the rather stereotyped and essentialized "Indian brave," M-W lists several archaic uses: a synonym for "bravado," or a "bully or assassin." *Taming of the Shrew* [seems to show](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=tamingshrew&Act=3&Scene=1&Scope=scene&LineHighlight=1282#1282) yet another, something akin to "taunts or insults."

Comment: On the basis that you'd like some comments, seeing posters using dictionaries for grammatical information causes some of us deep mental anguish. See John Lawler's post where he mentions: "This leads to things like looking up grammatical terms in a dictionary, which is about as useful as looking up natural logarithms in a dictionary"!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I'm not entirely sure . . . are you suggesting that I'm using the dictionary for grammar guidance? I consider dictionaries to be (relatively, of course!) authoritative on matters of lexicology, and I consider categorization of words by "part of speech" to be primarily an issue of lexicology, not grammar. I agree that dictionaries are generally not great for grammar.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Parts of speech are not primarily about lexicology! They are entirely about grammar! :-)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan [Here's why dictionaries can't do parts of speech](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part)!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I read through your answer there but am still not convinced. I’m certainly willing to be convinced, though, by good evidence. We’re wading a bit off-topic here, I think, but I’d be interested to discuss this on chat if you like.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Well, the fact that dictionaries haven't changed their part of speech classifications since the nineteenth century is evidence. The fact that the academic grammars of English published by Oxford disagree with the dictionaries published by Oxford is evidence. The evidence that *brave* is an adjective in Dryden's verse is that it must be modified by an adverb not an adjective: *Only the extremely brave deserve the fair* versus * *Only the extreme brave deserve the fair*. It's well documented! ;)

Comment: 1) Are you talking about things like "determiner" as a POS? That doesn't necessarily make a dictionary wrong. Even linguists / grammarians don't always agree on the "correct" way to categorize parts of speech. 2) That seems to be a problem with Oxford Univ. Press, not necessarily all dictionaries in general. 3) I agree with you (and many dictionaries) that "brave" is best considered an adjective, not noun. However, I'd like to know M-W's thinking on that before denouncing it entirely. Even if M-W did make a blatant mistake, grammars are hardly infallible, either.

Comment: 1) The basics, like  the difference between a noun and an adjective, not edge cases! 2) Oxford is the paragon of dictionaries whose depth of scholarship (in lexicography) is unparalleled. Every other dictionary has basically plagiarised from it directly or indirectly. Every publisher that publishes academic grammars of English publishes dictionaries. None of their dictionaries comply with what we've learned in the last 150 years of studying grammar. 3) M-W's thinking involves not understanding the difference between parts of speech and grammatical relations.

Answer (score 8):

So the question seems to have become, more generally, "What's a noun?"
That's a good question, and worth answering.

Let me start by mentioning the fact that most English speakers' idea of what ***noun*** means comes from grade school

> (i.e, what we used to call "grammar school", which is a very ironic term for linguists, since nobody ever learns English grammar in "grammar school" -- it's not taught in Anglophone schools -- and nobody ever studies English grammar after "grammar school").

Consequently, almost all discussion of English grammar conducted by adults is conducted at about the third-grade level, because that's where one finds the audience. This leads to things like looking up grammatical terms in a dictionary, which is about as useful as looking up natural logarithms in a dictionary. *Noun* is not defined in advance; it's determined by use.

*Noun* (from Latin *nomen* 'name') was one of the [*Partes Orationis*](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/don.html) 'parts of speech', a categorization from the late Roman Empire that was memorized by every schoolboy learning Latin (which meant every schoolboy) for well over a millennium.

The problem is the usual one with old conceptual machinery that's been sitting around for 1500 years -- parts are rusty and the original use is no longer useful and nobody talks that way any more -- so we have new parts of speech, with their own acronym - POS. The problem is that anybody can see there's more than 8 kinds of word. For sure, noun is one; but there's different kinds of noun. There's countable nouns and mass nouns. There's animate nouns and neuter nouns. There's abstract nouns and concrete nouns. And that's only nouns -- verbs have many more varieties; verbs run everything.

We were taught in grammar school that nouns are words that mean "a person, place, or thing". That sounds really definitive, until you get to nouns like *diagonalization, homeostasis,* or *presentiment*.

In fact, this is precisely backward. Nouns are not always persons, places, or things; but persons, places, and things are always nouns. So it's part right -- the easy third-grade part. As for the rest, it depends in part on how precise you want to get -- there are parsers with several hundred POS categories -- and in part what kind of analysis you want to do. Nouns in general are distinguished by their use in sentences. There has to be a noun (or at least a pronoun) in every noun phrase, and there has to be a noun phrase in every English sentence -- though it doesn't have to be audible, it does have to be understood.

Only nouns (and pronouns, which are usually easy to recognize because they're a closed class) can be subjects and objects of verbs in English. Which is to say that

- Anything used as the subject or object of an English sentence can be considered a noun.
  This includes multi-word constituents like subordinate clauses and prepositional phrases.

And this mean that being a noun is not a label stuck to a word in a dictionary, but to a constituent in a sentence. For instance, anything, including direct speech, following *He said* is a noun in that sentence. Any sentence preceding *is a shame* is a noun in **that** sentence. One's an object and the other's a subject, and there's an infinite number of each.

OK, so with an adjective that's got an article, like *the free* and *the brave*, you have a fixed phrase that means *the free people* and *the brave people*. It's a common construction with a definite article (*the*) plus some adjective that can describe a person (or a group of people), where *the `Adjective`* means 'people who are `Adjective`' -- *the homeless, the depraved, the tall, the college-educated*.

In this construction, the meaning is generic, group, and plural; *the tall* **can't** mean 'the tall person', the way it can in many languages†, and **a tall* doesn't mean anything at all, since the idiom requires a definite article.

---

> †For instance, Latin. The Latin grammarians who coined [the original Parts of Speech](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/don.html) did not, in fact, notice adjectives. They considered adjectives to be nouns without intrinsic gender, so they could take their gender from a noun they modified. Other than that, they behaved like nouns and took all the same endings, and an adjective that didn't modify a noun was taken to be a noun itself -- *longum* 'long [neut sg nom]' alone could mean 'a long thing', which the Romans correctly identified as a noun phrase, though only by treating *longus, -a, -um* as a noun. This is why technical terms like *noun* have to be related to theories that use them.

Comment: So what is your conclusion then, is a "collective adjective" a noun, given that the adjective _serves_ as a noun in a sentence?

Comment: @Lance There are different stipulative definitions.

Comment: Isn't it more common to call a phrase functioning as a noun a noun phrase instead of a noun?

Comment: @hkBst Expressions like "the rich", for example, **are** noun phrases. Here, "rich" is an adjective in a fused modifier-head noun phrase The fusion involves "rich" which serves simultaneously as head and modifier. We understand it to mean "rich people".